# Gparted: too many primary partitions

Tags: linux-mint, ntfs, gparted, fat32

I'm trying to create an external hard drive with NTFS part for info and hidden bootable fat32 part.

[image: gparted]

Here is an error

[image: error].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it does rather look like you've got a filesystem directly on the disk, without any partition table.

If that is the case you cannot have additional partitions without wiping the disk and starting over, this time with a partition table.